# Python script to download file from a published URL (public weblink)

Tags: python, html, json

Does anyone have any advice on the most effective way to download a file from a published public weblink. Google format example: drive.google.com/open?id=111111MMSvCyAhXXXXXXXXXXrPz-YYYYYYy although specifically we're trying to get this working with Intermedia's SecuriSync product.

These are public URL's so no login is required but typically it'll either open the file directly or download in Browser so they're not direct file downloads per se.

Code we've been trying:

```py
DownTo='%userprofile%/downloads'from URL='https://sharesync.serverdata.net/uk/s/file?public_share=hVv4gg20M0K4vT3WgoVTx500000464'
import ctypes
class disable_file_system_redirection:
    _disable = ctypes.windll.kernel32.Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection
    _revert = ctypes.windll.kernel32.Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection
    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_value = ctypes.c_long()
        self.success = self._disable(ctypes.byref(self.old_value))
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.success:
            self._revert(self.old_value)

import subprocess        
with disable_file_system_redirection(): 
        import urllib
import os

def downloadFile(DownTo, fromURL):
    try:
        fileName = fromURL.split('/')[-1]
        DownTo = os.path.join(DownTo, fileName)
        with open(DownTo, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(urllib.urlopen(fromURL).read())
        if os.path.isfile(DownTo):
            return '{} - {}KB'.format(DownTo, os.path.getsize(DownTo)/1000)
    except:
        return 'Please Check URL or Download Path!'

if __name__=='__main__':
    print downloadFile(DownTo, fromURL )here
```

We've also been trying some other variations but finding this method is not handling larger file sizes well (example file is around 800kb).

```py
import os
import urllib

url = "http://web.archive.org/web/20100105072145/http://cmrr.ucsd.edu/people/Hughes"
dest_dir = os.path.expandvars('%userprofile%/Desktop')

try:
    os.makedirs(dest_dir)
except OSError:
    pass

urllib.urlretrieve(url, os.path.join(dest_dir, 'HDDEraseWeb.zip'))
```

Comment: How does _Intermedia’s SecuriSync_ come into play here? Have you done any research, encountered any specific issues? Also _Python or JSON download file_ doesn’t make much sense, do you mean that the file is JSON?

Comment: SecuriSync is just the product in question where the file is - I was trying to be specific but the issue exists with all Cloud storage products. The file can be anything. If you share a file using a public weblink from Cloud storage they generally force you to access the file through a Browser. We're trying to write a script to download these files directly. Does that make a bit more sense?

Comment: I've corrected the title to be clearer.

Comment: Yes, that does make more sense, thank you :) I imagine that this is going to need to be service-specific to some extent, right?

Comment: Well, I don't know to be honest although quite possibly!

Comment: Do you have an example link for SecuriSync? Have you tried anything yet, any ideas?

Comment: So yea, I've added the code and actual link above (the file is a harmless little mousejiggle exe). we've been trying with $WebClient.DownloadFile powershell command as well but just end up with the HTML.

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a try!

Comment: I may have found something that will work, but I'm stuck trying to set up my environment. Do you know of a good way of installing and isolating Chrome?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't.

Comment: I commented on your new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, managed to get this working finally thanks to some help. Posting here in case any one else wants it. It works with GoogleDrive and not quite with ShareSync which is what I want ideally but I'll open a second question on that.

```py
import os
DownTo = os.path.join(os.path.join(os.environ['USERPROFILE']), 'Desktop')
fileName='MouseJiggle.exe'
fromURL='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

import ctypes
print DownTo

class disable_file_system_redirection:
    _disable = ctypes.windll.kernel32.Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection
    _revert = ctypes.windll.kernel32.Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection
    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_value = ctypes.c_long()
        self.success = self._disable(ctypes.byref(self.old_value))
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        if self.success:
            self._revert(self.old_value)

import subprocess        
with disable_file_system_redirection(): 
        import urllib
import os

def downloadFile(DownTo, fromURL, fileName):
    try:
        DownTo = os.path.join(DownTo, fileName)
        print "DownTo",DownTo
        print "fileName",fileName
        with open(DownTo, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(urllib.urlopen(fromURL).read())
        if os.path.isfile(DownTo):
            return '{} - {}KB'.format(DownTo, os.path.getsize(DownTo)/1000)
    except:
        return 'Please Check URL or Download Path!'

if __name__=='__main__':
    print downloadFile(DownTo, fromURL, fileName)
```